# Jquery - Sorting nested ul list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to sort the following list:

```
<ul id="continenti_nazioni" class="open" style="display: block;">
    <li class="continent"><a href="javascript:open_c('Asia')" class="continent_link  Asia">Asia</a>
        <ul style="display: none;">
            <li class="nation "><a href="nation_50">Cina</a></li>
            <li class="nation "><a href="nation_35">Giappone</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="continent"><a href="javascript:open_c('Europa')" class="continent_link  Europa active">Europa</a>
        <ul style="display: block;">
            <li class="nation "><a href="#">Austria</a></li>
            <li class="nation "><a href="nation_15">Belgio</a></li>
            <li class="nation "><a href="nation_42">Republica Ceca</a></li>
            <li class="nation "><a href="nation_32">Francia</a></li>
            <li class="nation "><a href="nation_37">Germany</a></li>
            <li class="nation "><a href="nation_40">Olanda</a></li>
            <li class="nation "><a href="nation_41">Portogallo</a></li>
            <li class="nation "><a href="nation_43">Russia</a></li>
            <li class="nation "><a href="nation_44">Spagna</a></li>
            <li class="nation "><a href="nation_36">Svizzera</a></li>
            <li class="nation "><a href="nation_38">Regno Unito</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="continent"><a href="javascript:open_c('Medio-Oriente')" class="continent_link  Medio-Oriente">Medio Oriente</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="nation ">
                <a href="nation_47"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nation "><a href="nation_46">Bahrain</a></li>
            <li class="nation "><a href="nation_48">Qatar</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="continent"><a href="javascript:open_c('Nord-America')" class="continent_link  Nord-America">Nord America</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="nation "><a href="nation_16">USA</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="continent"><a href="javascript:open_c('Pan-Regional')" class="continent_link  Pan-Regional">Pan Regional</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="nation "><a href="nation_33">Globale</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="continent"><a href="javascript:open_c('Sud-America')" class="continent_link  Sud-America">Sud America</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="nation "><a href="nation_31">Brasile</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and I'm using the following js:

```
function sortUl(selector) {
    var mylist = jQuery(selector);
    var listitems = mylist.children('li').get();
    listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
        return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare(jQuery(b).text().toUpperCase());
    })
    jQuery.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) { mylist.append(itm); });
}
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    sortUl('#continenti_nazioni');
    sortUl('#continenti_nazioni > li > ul');
});
```

It works fine for the first level of the `ul` but when I try to sort the second level the list gets broken. 
Is there somethink I can do to make that function works also for the nested `ul`?

**EDIT**

```js
function sortUl(mylist) {
    var listitems = mylist.children('li').get();
    listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
        return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare(jQuery(b).text().toUpperCase());
    })
    jQuery.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) { mylist.append(itm); });
}
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    sortUl(jQuery('.nazioni'));
    sortUl(jQuery('#filter_archive'));
    jQuery('#filter_archive > li > ul').each(function () {
      sortUl(jQuery(this));
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nazioni">
        <li><a href="#">Russia</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Spagna</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Svizzera</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Austria</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Belgio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Francia</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Germany</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Olanda</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portogallo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Regno Unito</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Republica Ceca</a></li>
    </ul>
    
<ul id="continenti_nazioni" class="open" style="display: block;">
    <li class="continent"><a href="javascript:open_c('Asia')" class="continent_link  Asia">Asia</a>
        <ul style="display: none;">
            <li class="nation "><a href="nation_50">Cina</a></li>
            <li class="nation "><a href="nation_35">Giappone</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="continent"><a href="javascript:open_c('Europa')" class="continent_link  Europa active">Europa</a>
        <ul style="display: block;">
            <li class="nation "><a href="#">Austria</a></li>
            <li class="nation "><a href="nation_15">Belgio</a></li>
            <li class="nation "><a href="nation_42">Republica Ceca</a></li>
            <li class="nation "><a href="nation_32">Francia</a></li>
            <li class="nation "><a href="nation_37">Germany</a></li>
            <li class="nation "><a href="nation_40">Olanda</a></li>
            <li class="nation "><a href="nation_41">Portogallo</a></li>
            <li class="nation "><a href="nation_43">Russia</a></li>
            <li class="nation "><a href="nation_44">Spagna</a></li>
            <li class="nation "><a href="nation_36">Svizzera</a></li>
            <li class="nation "><a href="nation_38">Regno Unito</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="continent"><a href="javascript:open_c('Medio-Oriente')" class="continent_link  Medio-Oriente">Medio Oriente</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="nation ">
                <a href="nation_47"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nation "><a href="nation_46">Bahrain</a></li>
            <li class="nation "><a href="nation_48">Qatar</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="continent"><a href="javascript:open_c('Nord-America')" class="continent_link  Nord-America">Nord America</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="nation "><a href="nation_16">USA</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="continent"><a href="javascript:open_c('Pan-Regional')" class="continent_link  Pan-Regional">Pan Regional</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="nation "><a href="nation_33">Globale</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="continent"><a href="javascript:open_c('Sud-America')" class="continent_link  Sud-America">Sud America</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="nation "><a href="nation_31">Brasile</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The selector `#continenti_nazioni` returns just one `ul`. The other one `#continenti_nazioni > li > ul` returns multiple. I'm guessing that's your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution:

```
function sortUl(mylist) {
    var listitems = mylist.children('li').get();
    listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
        return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare(jQuery(b).text().toUpperCase());
    })
    jQuery.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) { mylist.append(itm); });
}
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    sortUl($('#continenti_nazioni'));
    $('#continenti_nazioni > li > ul').each(function () {
      sortUl($(this));
    });
});
```

I'm passing the jQuery `ul` to the function instead of the selector, then calling the sort method for each inner `ul` separately.

Comment: I still have the same problem, all the items get duplicated if the list is only one level deep.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle.net that reproduces this problem? You can also try adding `mylist.html("");` to the sort function, right before the final line.

Comment: I prepare it now

Comment: it works! There was a conflict with another part of the code...
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Because `sortUl('#continenti_nazioni > li > ul');`
 return array all ul in `#continenti_nazioni`.And `var mylist = jQuery(selector);` will return all li in `#continenti_nazioni`.

You each all `li` sort and append to all `ul`

Replace to

```js
function sortUl(mylist) {
    var listitems = mylist.children('li').get();
    listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
        return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare(jQuery(b).text().toUpperCase());
    })
    jQuery.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) {
        mylist.append(itm);
       // check current item has ul and sort child
        if(jQuery(itm).children('ul').length){
          sortUl(jQuery(itm).children('ul'));
       }
   });
}
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    sortUl($('#nazioni_continenti'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nazioni_continenti" class="open" style="display: block;">
<li class="continent"><a href="javascript:open_c('Asia')" class="continent_link  Asia">Asia</a>
    <ul style="display: none;">
        <li class="nation "><a href="nation_50">Cina</a></li>
        <li class="nation "><a href="nation_35">Giappone</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="continent"><a href="javascript:open_c('Europa')" class="continent_link  Europa active">Europa</a>
    <ul style="display: block;">
        <li class="nation "><a href="#">Austria</a></li>
        <li class="nation "><a href="nation_15">Belgio</a></li>
        <li class="nation "><a href="nation_42">Republica Ceca</a></li>
        <li class="nation "><a href="nation_32">Francia</a></li>
        <li class="nation "><a href="nation_37">Germany</a></li>
        <li class="nation "><a href="nation_40">Olanda</a></li>
        <li class="nation "><a href="nation_41">Portogallo</a></li>
        <li class="nation "><a href="nation_43">Russia</a></li>
        <li class="nation "><a href="nation_44">Spagna</a></li>
        <li class="nation "><a href="nation_36">Svizzera</a></li>
        <li class="nation "><a href="nation_38">Regno Unito</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="continent"><a href="javascript:open_c('Medio-Oriente')" class="continent_link  Medio-Oriente">Medio Oriente</a>
    <ul>
        <li class="nation ">
            <a href="nation_47"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nation "><a href="nation_46">Bahrain</a></li>
        <li class="nation "><a href="nation_48">Qatar</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="continent"><a href="javascript:open_c('Nord-America')" class="continent_link  Nord-America">Nord America</a>
    <ul>
        <li class="nation "><a href="nation_16">USA</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="continent"><a href="javascript:open_c('Pan-Regional')" class="continent_link  Pan-Regional">Pan Regional</a>
    <ul>
        <li class="nation "><a href="nation_33">Globale</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="continent"><a href="javascript:open_c('Sud-America')" class="continent_link  Sud-America">Sud America</a>
    <ul>
        <li class="nation "><a href="nation_31">Brasile</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: I works for the nested list, but only for nested. I have other lists with only one level where I uses the same script and now every list has 2 element of the same item.

Comment: You can add class `nested` for ul.and check `        if(jQuery(itm).children('ul.nested').length){
          sortUl(jQuery(itm).children('ul.nested'));
       }`